# Is $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ the $\ell^p$-direct sum of $L^p([0,1])$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Given a sequence of Banach spaces $(A_n)_{n\geq 1}$ and $1\leq p\leq\infty$, we can form the direct sum $\bigoplus_{n\geq1}A_n$, where the norm of a sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq1}$ is defined to be the $\ell^p$-norm of the sequence $(\|a_n\|_{A_n})_{n\geq1}$. Now there is a map $F:L^p(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}L^p([n,n+1])$ that restricts an $L^p$ function to each of the intervals $[n,n+1]$. I feel like this is an isometry between $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ and the ($\ell^p$-direct sum) $\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}L^p([n,n+1])$, because $(\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} f_n)^p=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} f_n^p$ (almost everywhere) if $f_n$ is supported on $[n,n+1]$. Is this correct? If so does this mean the study of $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ can be reduced to the study of $L^p([0,1])$ to some extent?

Comment: The answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3747334/121671) may be what you need.

Comment: [Here](https://www.math.tamu.edu/~schlump/lecture24and25.pdf) you will find that if $(X,\mathscr{F})$ countably generated, and $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure of $(X,\mathscr{F})$, $L_p(X,\mu)$, $1\leq p<\infty$,  is isometrically isomorphic to $L_p[0,1]\oplus\ell_p(I)$ for some countable set $I$.  If $\mu$ has no atoms then one can take $I=\emptyset$.

Comment: It seems correct. But the reduction is not convincing, depending on "to some extent". For example for $1\le p <2$ we have $L^2(0,1)\subset L^p(0,1)$ and $\ell^p\subset \ell^2.$ So the inclusion are opposite.